# body override not being applied via sass override with Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, gulp

I am using Gulp and Boostrap to put together a theme. I have `main.scss` file which has the following code:

```
@import 'base/_base.scss';
@import 'base/_mixins.scss';
@import 'base/_variables.scss';
@import 'layouts/_footer.scss';
@import 'layouts/_header.scss';
@import 'layouts/_nav.scss';
@import 'modules/_typography.scss';
@import 'modules/_blocks.scss';
@import 'modules/_buttons.scss';
@import 'modules/_sections.scss';
@import 'modules/_components.scss';
@import "bootstrap";
@import "bootstrap/theme";
```

Bootstrap is being loaded ok as I can see it in a index page I have. The issue comes is when I add code to e.g. _base.scss. I added the following:

```
body {
 font-size: 16px;
 line-height: 1.5em;
 color: #666666;
}
```

and then ran `gulp` and I can see that it generated a css `main.css` file for me, which the index page is using. I can see the body override at the top of the `main.css` file, but when I load the page it isnt being applied. I can see in inspect element that it is being overridden by bootstrap definition of body further down.

I did another test and set `$font-size-base: 16px;` and ran `gulp` and it applied that change fine.

If anyone can point me in the right direction, it would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see it you have 2 choices.

```
body 
{
 font-size: 16px !important;
 line-height: 1.5em  !important;
 color: #666666 !important;
}
```

1. You load your css file after bootstrap.
2. In your css file you add !important to the end of anything you want to override like above.

Comment: Woudnt that then mean I need to apply !important to every single thing in the override file?

Comment: yeah, not that good if you have lots. You really should try and get your one loading after bootstrap.

Comment: I have amended my scss file to load boostrap first. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```
html body {
 font-size: 16px;
 line-height: 1.5em;
 color: #666666;
}
```